# Firebase Ionic Nested Search

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to make a search function. 
When a user selects a product, a list of products should be shown belonging to some storage place.

For so far, I can only show the array Products with all the items in it. But when I want to go deeper and loop over each items (to search items that match with the selected item), I got an error:

> Error: No index defined for Products

This is my code:

controllers.js:

```
.controller('InventoryCtrl', function($scope, Category, Inventory) {
$scope.categories = Category;


$scope.searchInventory = function(category){
var word = category.Category;
//console.log(word);


var ref = new Firebase('https://vivid-heat-2430.firebaseio.com/');
var invenRef = ref.child('Inventories');
var prodRef = invenRef.child('Products');


invenRef.orderByChild("Products").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();
  var store = data.Inventory;
  var prod = data.Products;
  console.log(prod);


  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var test = childSnapshot.val();
    console.log(test);
    //var key = childSnapshot.key();
    //console.log(key);
  });

});
};
})
```

I’ve already defined my index. But I still got this error.

I also tried it like this in my controller:

```
$scope.searchInventory = function(category){
var word = category.Category;

var ref = new Firebase('https://vivid-heat-2430.firebaseio.com/');
var invenRef = ref.child('Inventories');
var prodRef = invenRef.child('Products');

invenRef.orderByChild("Products").equalTo(word).on("child_added", function(snapshot){
  console.log(snapshot.key());
});
};
})
```

Here I got no errors, But I can't log anything to see.

This is my firebase structure:

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN0Tv.png)

Can you please point out what I did wrong? I'm still new to this and trying to learn from my mistakes.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

My rules.json

```
{
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "Inventories": {
    ".indexOn": "Products"
    }
}
}
```

JSON file of db structure:

```
{
  "Categorie" : {
    "-K5a3iGlgi7PS0m3O4y8" : {
      "Category" : "IQ 33cl BOX",
      "Optional" : false,
      "Size" : "24"
    },
    "-K5a3vNZRc2Cur9964Xs" : {
      "Category" : "CL 33cl BOX",
      "Optional" : true,
      "Size" : "24"
    },
    "-K5a40Q79SCqWqMbqWQu" : {
      "Category" : "IQ 33cl CASE",
      "Optional" : true,
      "Size" : "24"
    },
    "-K5a464FON4qdnqE9rgf" : {
      "Category" : "CL 33cl CASE",
      "Optional" : false,
      "Size" : "24"
    },
    "-K5a4TAzHE8cRGPbNeij" : {
      "Category" : "Empty CASES",
      "Optional" : false,
      "Size" : "24"
    }
  },
  "Inventories" : {
    "17-12-2015Storage 1" : {
      "Date" : 1450366396979,
      "Inventory" : "Storage 1",
      "Products" : {
        "CL 33cl BOX" : {
          "boxes" : 0,
          "full" : 11,
          "half" : 13
        },
        "IQ 33cl BOX" : {
          "boxes" : 0,
          "full" : 60,
          "half" : 0
        }
      }
    },
    "17-12-2015Storage Deb" : {
      "Date" : 1450367128198,
      "Inventory" : "Storage Deb",
      "Products" : {
        "IQ 33cl CASE" : {
          "boxes" : 0,
          "full" : 2,
          "half" : 14
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Storages" : {
    "-K5a4esu-1Na1hkKMP47" : { "name" : "Storage 1" },
    "-K5a4ihb9L5z6qSqQxAx" : { "name" : "Storage Deb" },
    "-K5a4l9odWuPUJJuN8OR" : { "name" : "Storage Bart" },
    "-K5a4nsc47N3k_hMVl2h" : { "name" : "Storage Debosz" }
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<div style="max-height: 300px" ng-controller="InventoryCtrl">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-radio ng-repeat="category in categories" class="item-accordion" ng-model="checked.check" value="{{category.Category}}" ng-click="searchInventory(category)">
          <p>{{category.Category}}</p>
        </ion-radio>
        <br>
      </ion-list>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show how your define the index in your rules.json?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just edited my post with the rules.json

Comment: OK, thanks. That gets us closer. Now instead of linking to an image of the JSON structure, can you get that JSON into a textual format and include it *in* the question? That will also solve the problem that the image is not showing the deeper structure, which is likely relevant to the problem. A quick way to get the JSON is export it from the Firebase dashboard.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added the json in the question

Comment: The formatting is throwing me off a bit but is Products a child of "17-12-2015Storage 1" which is a child of Inventories?

Comment: What are typical values of `word` that you're trying to search for?

Comment: @Jay Yes you're right

Comment: For example, this gives me a result: `invenRef.orderByChild('Products/CL 33cl BOX/boxes').equalTo(0).once('value', function(s) { console.log(s.val()); })` (using JavaScript  because it's faster for me to test)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The "word" variable is where I store the selected product the user wants to search for. For example the user selects "CL 33cl BOX". Then I need to search in Products of each inventory to make a match and show it to the user in which storage places this product belongs

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen For now I've added this: 
`var test = Object.keys(prod); 
    
      for( var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
        if (test[i] == word) {
          console.log(test[i]);
          console.log("Storage place: " + data.Inventory + " Datum inventaris: " + data.Date);

        };
        
      };`

This works but I don’t know whether it is a proper way to get the product name. It makes a match with the products and gives me the right storage places to which it belongs.

Comment: Please don't add blocks of code to comments. Update your original question with the formatted code. It will help us... help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using Object.keys() to get the name of the products.

I also used a for loop to search for the matching product.

My controller looks like this now:

```
.controller('InventoryCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject, Category, Inventory) {

$scope.categories = Category;

$scope.searchInventory = function(category){
var word = category.Category;

var ref = new Firebase('https://vivid-heat-2430.firebaseio.com/');

var invenRef = ref.child('Inventories');
var prodRef = invenRef.child('Products');

var test22 = [];

invenRef.orderByChild("Products").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();
  var store = data.Inventory;
  var test = Object.keys(prod);

  for( var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
    if (test[i] == word) {        
     test22.push(data.Inventory);
    };        
  }; 
  $scope.show = test22;
});
 };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your structure (according to the link)

```
Inventories
  some_node_name_1
    Inventory: xxxx
    Products:
      product_name: "product a"
      product_price: 30
  some_node_name_2
    Inventory: xxxx
    Products:
      product_name: "product b"
      product_price: 50
```

and your query path

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://vivid-heat-2430.firebaseio.com/');
var invenRef = ref.child('Inventories');
var prodRef = invenRef.child('Products');
```

(note prodRef doesn't appear to be used)

So how about:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://vivid-heat-2430.firebaseio.com/Inventories');
  ref.orderByChild("Products/product_name").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
});
```

And the .indexOn rule should be at the same level as where you do the query (product_name).

Edit with more info:

A nodes key is indexed automatically so you don't need to add .index for the node Products (it's already done). However, you would add a index for a child of Products for example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Inventories": {
        "Products": {
           ".indexOn": ["product_name"]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

or (I believe this is another option)

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Inventories": {
       ".indexOn": ["Products/product_name"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I was unclear in asking my question. In Products there are different items. When searching for an item I need the query in products to match an item. For example, if I’ve selected yyyyy to search, then I need to find yyyyy in products. I don’t need to go deeper in yyyyy. So if I’m correct, my .indexOn rule is still right?

Comment: This is bothering me  orderByChild("Products").  What is the expected result as Products is a node name and doesn't have a direct value associated with it? See my edited answer above